# How to display agent's parameters' values in Main (Anylogic simulation)

Tags: parameters, program-entry-point, anylogic, agent, getvalue

I am working on an Anylogic model in which I have created an agent with some parameters in the agent window.
However, when I call an agent's parameter in Main using agent.parameter I get a value of 0 instead of the actual parameter's value.
Please note that I have already dragged the agent type into Main so Main has access to all agent's parameters and objects however it displays all parameters values as zeroes.
My agent is fondoir_ss as displayed below

[image]

Below is an example of a parameter defined in fondoir_ss

[image]

The parameter I am interested in is defined as a result of other parameters (inside agent fondoir_ss)

[image]

Now the problem emerges when I add my parameter to main : I create a parameter that contains the value of the parameter from agent fondoir_ss.

However, when I launch the simulation "parameter" has a value of 0 whereas the value of 'PAR_demande_fusion_jour' is equal to 600 in agent fondoir_ss.

[image]
How can I solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some screenshots, this seems a very basic issue. You probably did not actually set the agent parameter value correctly.

Comment: I have added some screenshots for better explanation

Comment: likely that agent has not been instantiated yet so the parameter on Main takes the default value instead. These are just initial values. You need to understand how agents are instantiated and how other parameters "read" off that. I suggest you build an extremely simple example model to reproduce the issue and report back here.

Comment: I tried using a simpler model yet the issue persisted. Finally I have used the function set_parameter(value) at the beginning of each simulation run and it worked.